# Extjs 4 and sencha touch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sencha-touch, extjs4

I wrote an application with extjs 4 (java backend).

I'd now like to write a sencha touch(mobile app) for the same thing.

Do I create a whole new project or just add the code within the current project, because I'd like to use the already written java code.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse your java backend. You can simply redirect the user to appropriate version, depending of the device.